# How to order this by DESC

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code bellow is a code to add the comments automatically without refresh.

And when it runs it add's the div's ordered by ASC and i want it to order the div's by DESC, anyone around here have any idea how can i do this?

Thanks.

```
$("#send").click(function() {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "http://localhost/index.php?/main/add_comment",
         data: {
             textbox: $("#textbox").val()
         },
         dataType: "text",
         cache: false,
         success: function(data) {
             document.getElementById('comments').innerHTML += "<div class=\"col-lg-6\">" +
                 "<div class=\"well well-sm\">" +
                 "<div class=\"col-md-2 comment-img\">" +
                 "<img src=\"/img/avatar_img.png\"> " +
                 "</div>" +
                 "<div class=\"col-md-10\">" +
                 "<p class=\"text-left\">admin said:<pre>" + data + "</pre></p>" +
                 "<p class=\"text-right timeago\">Posted 0 secounds ago.</p>" +
                 "</div>" +
                 "<div class=\"clearfix\">" +
                 "</div>" +
                 "</div>" +
                 "</div>";

         }
     });
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: I don't understand... the code you posted just replaces the comments div with the data returned. I don't see that there is many comments. If you want your comment to show before every other comment, use $('#comments').prepend('YOUR HTML HERE');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `document.getElementById('comments').innerHTML` by `document.getElementById('comments').insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", theHTML);`

```
success: function (data) {
    var HTMLtext = "<div class=\"col-lg-6\">" +
        "<div class=\"well well-sm\">" +
        "<div class=\"col-md-2 comment-img\">" +
        "<img src=\"/img/avatar_img.png\"> " +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class=\"col-md-10\">" +
        "<p class=\"text-left\">admin said:<pre>" + data + "</pre></p>" +
        "<p class=\"text-right timeago\">Posted 0 secounds ago.</p>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class=\"clearfix\">" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>";
        document.getElementById('comments').insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",HTMLtext);
}
```